# SonarQube not failing my local maven build, but is failing our CI build

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, sonarqube

The company I work for uses SonarQube as part of our CI build.

I have configured my settings.xml file according to: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

I am pointing my local build at the same SonarQube server that is used by our CI build.

My build fails on the CI server as a result of the SQ analysis.

When I perform `mvn sonar:sonar` on my machine I am expecting a failed build with some helpful error messages. Instead, the build succeeds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you testing against the same SonarQube server, or a local server on your machine? The build can fail due to a difference in configuration for the quality gates.

Comment: please show us the command on CI side, and some logs output

Comment: I don't have access to the command on the CI side, or the logs output. I'm only a dev, not on the CI team.

Comment: As @PieterjanDeconinck mentioned, if you are running the scans against different sonarqube instances, the differences might be the Quality Profile - which contains the set of rules and conditions of your code - or might be the Quality Gate - which contains the thresholds allowed for the metrics taken based on the profile rules. You should make sure that you also have the same Sonarqube server version.

Comment: I'm pointing my local build at the same SonarQube server that is used by our CI build.